# Unable to install mongodb properly on ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am trying to install mongodb on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but it has the following error saying

> You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. The
>   following packages have unmet dependencies:  mongodb-org : Depends:
>   mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
>                  Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
>                  Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with
>   no packages (or specify a solution).
>   umar@umar-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15ISK:~/Desktop/portfolio/async-demo$
>   sudo apt-get install -y mongodb

I beleieve the reason behind this is already mentioned on their website, clearly saying

> PLATFORM SUPPORT
>
> MongoDB only provides packages for 64-bit LTS (long-term support)
>   Ubuntu releases; for example, 14.04 LTS (trusty) and 16.04 LTS
>   (xenial). See Supported Platforms for more information.
>
> These packages may work with other Ubuntu releases; however, they are
>   not supported.

So how can I install mongodb on my latest Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?
For sake of clarity, I am listing the things I did to correct the errors:
I followed their official website to install mongodb

```
1. sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
2. echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

> Now here I got errors saying: You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken
>   install' to correct these. The following packages have unmet
>   dependencies:

I tried,

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

It did not work, somewhere I got clue to run

```
sudo apt -f install
```

It also returned error.

> Errors were encountered while processing: 
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.0.0_amd64.deb 
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.0.0_amd64.deb 
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_4.0.0_amd64.deb E:
>   Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I believe the main problem is compatability with version. So basically I have Ubuntu 18.04, how I install mongodb on this version, so that I can work without any trouble.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You need to first uninstall the mongodb, you can use:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

After this, install mongodb through the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

And then update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You are done with the installation of mongodb. You can check it by using the below command:

```
mongo --version
```

Comment: $ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2019-06-19T00:03:01.844+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2019-06-19T00:03:01.845+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed

Comment: Install is now ok for me but unable to launch (couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017)

Comment: this is for older mongo version

Comment: This works! Thank you. I would just like to add that if someone is using a different shell then bash, and for some reason your shell throws you an error, it might not be your fault. I was writing these out in ZSH, but for some reason the 1st step was not even being recognized by ZSH that there were `mongodb-org*` packages - clearly there were, I checked. Then I switched over to BASH, and the same commands worked flawlessly.

Comment: Shouldn't we done `sudo apt-get update` before `sudo apt-get install mongodb`

Comment: Can we use that commend to install mongo v4.4?

Comment: This does not instal mongo > v4

Comment: just an fyi '*' doesnt' work in zsh. use bash

Answer (score 27):

EDIT: It's been a number of years, and unfortunately the top answer still points users away from the latest stable version of MongoDB. In fact the last available package for [`mongodb`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mongodb&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) is 3.6.3.

I don't work at the company anymore, but I will point to:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

That's the best way to install the latest stable version MongoDB. It includes instructions for adding the necessary repositories and keys to allow running `apt install mongodb-org`. There is a [platform support matrix](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/production-notes/#platform-support-matrix) that will help with identifying which versions of MongoDB you can install on any given Linux OS version.

just want to chime in here. I'm the Senior Technical Writer for MongoDB Server Docs. This post is one of a few that comes up with "install MongoDB on Ubuntu 18.04", and there are several comments here referencing the `mongodb` package for installation. The unofficial `mongodb` package provided by Ubuntu is not maintained by MongoDB. You should always use the official MongoDB `mongodb-org` packages. Furthermore, from a bit of personal testing it looks like having `mongodb` installed will cause issues if you try to install `mongodb-org`, so its just added trouble

The few times I've run into this issue when testing locally, attempting to install one of the subpackages (i.e. `mongodb-org-server`) usually surfaced the actual error (i.e. missing `libcurl3`, which was removed in 18.04 as a default installed library). These issues may be more common when testing development builds ( at the time of writing, that's the 4.2 dev series).

To check which package you have installed on your local system, run the following:

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep mongo
```

This was my output after I installed `mongodb`, then attempted `mongodb-org`:

```
mongo-tools/bionic,now 3.6.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
mongodb-org/bionic,now 4.0.5 amd64 [installed]
mongodb-org-shell/bionic,now 4.0.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mongodb-server-core/bionic,now 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
```

So you can see, I've got a mix between the two packages (and a bunch of `dkpg` errors). I ended up using a mix of `apt remove` , `apt autoremove`, and `apt purge` to fix up the system.

Comment: But I came here because I could not find answer in your docs for this specific version of Ubuntu (18). In the docs there is a ulimit -n <value> command mentioned which does not work. and with sudo it does not recognize the command itself. I have been searching a solution for this, ended up editing several different .conf files also

Comment: When I try `sudo apt install mongodb-org`, I get `E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org`. How do I get past this?

Comment: For other people who hit the same error, I needed to follow the instructions here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Could you please suggest an installation that works then ?

Answer (score 12):

Based on this excellent Answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51421152/659354

And this Page:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

The commands I used to install **MongoDB 4.2**

`sudo apt-get purge mongo*` - **Note:** mongo to remove the client as well as the server.

`sudo apt-get install mongodb-org` - **Note:** install command run after the Mongodb.org Source was added to the Apt-get sources list.

Comment: Thanks, purging `mongo*` instead of `mongodb-org*` solved it for me.

Answer (score 7):

This is because as of now Mongo DB for Ubuntu 18.04 is only available as a development version (See: [MongoDB Distros](http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/)).

I just installed it by doing the following:

Add the corresponding signature:

```
    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4B7C549A058F8B6B
```

Add the supported version:

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/development multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
```

Update:

```
    sudo apt update
```

Install:

```
sudo apt install mongodb-org-unstable
```

If you get a "GPG error" repeat step 1 with the key that is shown in the error message. You might be able to install via

```
sudo apt install mongodb
```

but according to MongoDB this is not supported and will most probably not install the newest version.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to install MongoDB and use the `mongod` command on ubuntu 18.04.

1. Update the packages list.

   ```
    $ sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install the MongoDB.

   ```
    $ sudo apt install -y mongodb
   ```
3. Check the service's status.

   ```
    $ sudo systemctl status mongodb
   ```

   3a. You should see

   ```
    ● mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor 
      preset:enabled)
      Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-03-11 10:45:01 UTC; 4min 13s ago
      Docs: man:mongod(1)
      Main PID: 2312 (mongod)
      Tasks: 23 (limit: 1153)
      CGroup: /system.slice/mongodb.service
            └─2312 /usr/bin/mongod --unixSocketPrefix=/run/mongodb --config
      /etc/mongodb.conf
   ```
4. To allow access to MongoDB on its default `port 27017`

   ```
     $ sudo ufw allow 27017
   ```
5. Check status

   ```
     $ sudo ufw status
   ```

5a. You should see

```
     Status: active
     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
     27017                      ALLOW       Anywhere
     27017 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

5b. If it returns `inactive`

```
     $ sudo ufw enable

     Output:
     Firewall is active and enabled on system startup.
```

6. Check the `/` directory to see if there is a `data/db` directory, if not:

   ```
     $ sudo mkdir -p /data/db
   ```
7. To run the `mongod` first you need stop mongodb:

   ```
     $ sudo systemctl stop mongodb
   ```
8. Finally, you can run the `mongod`:

   ```
     $ sudo mongod
   ```

Answer (score 3):

`cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

remove files related to mongodb

`sudo apt update`

This solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall and remove any Mongo packages.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

Check if related directories removed

```
$ sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
$ sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

Recheck for autoremove any remaining mongo packages

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Configure your directory

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Force install anything required

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

Install from official site: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Finally restart your Ubuntu and check status of Mogodb server as you did earlier.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to install mongodb binary (Manually) to your Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic). You need to download mongodb .tgz file from this [link](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=docs#production) .

1) Download it to your ~/Downloads folder and moveit to home directory by typing `mv Downloads/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-4.0.4.tgz ~/`

2) Then unter it by typing `tar -zxvf mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-4.0.4.tgz` place it here (Home directory /home/). Dont move it from here.

3) Then make a directory at /data/db location and give write permission to thatdirectory.

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db

sudo chmod -R 777 /data/db
```

4) Now, this is the tricky area. Make sure u r in hme directory by typing pwd (Present Working Directory)

```
pwd
```

it will show

```
/home/<your user name>
```

Then type

`ls -al`

This command will show up all hiddenfile at home directory and search for

`~/.bashrc`

5) Edit the .bashrc file and write

```
export PATH=mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-4.0.4/bin:$PATH
```

and save the file type `source ./bashrc`

Then type `echo $PATH` at terminal it will display `~/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1804-4.0.4/bin:/home/xenon/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin`

6) Now at terminal type `mongo --nodb`
it will show `MongoDB shell version v4.0.4`

From here , you are all set, go ahead and enjoy mongodb installation. This istallation is bit complex but by this method you can easily control the version of mongodb and use it as per your need.
[image]

7) Then start mongod

```
>sudo mkdir -p /var/log && sudo chmod -R 777 /var/log
>mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --logpath /var/log/local.log --fork
>mongo --port 27017
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and for me the solution was purge, but with the (*) . Purge everything, so i did this:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongo-tools*
sudo apt-get purge mongodb*
```

then i follow the steps from the documentation. (Actual version is 4.2.2), and the installation was in Ubuntu 18.04. (URL: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

With that four steps from the documentation i finally install mongodb community edition on Ubuntu. My problem was 3 files,that can't process.

```
mongodb-org-server
mongodb-org-mongos
mongodb-org-tools
```

I hope its help someone

Answer (score 1):

run `sudo apt autoremove` and re-install **mongodb** .

Answer (score 1):

**For Ubuntu version 18.04 LTS, it's better if you will install MongoDB manually.**

**I need to go through the following steps to make it run on my Ubuntu 18.04:**

1. Fallow manual installation steps from the following mongo DB manual
   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-tarball/
2. Download .tgz with the following configurations
   [Download MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcLC2.png)
3. Please note, when you install MongoDB 3.6 or above, it comes up with Curl library of "libcurl4" version and which has some compatibility issues on ubuntu 18.04
4. Due to this, you will end up resulting following output when try to execute "mongod" command:

> mongod: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version
>   `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by mongod)

5. To fix this problem, you need to uninstall "libcurl4" dependent library by using the following command

   sudo apt-get remove libcurl4
6. Then need to install back lower curl lib version (i.e. "libcurl3"), as mongo expects it on ubuntu version "18.04"

   sudo apt-get install libcurl3
7. You may need to use "sudo" to fork the data and log directories with the installation if it fails with the manual steps

   sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --fork
8. you can run "mongo" command now to see the mongo shell running.

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a libssl1.1 issue when trying to install mongo-db in Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS (or Ubuntu 22.04 LTS).

1. Go to http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl
2. Find the exact version of libssl for example libssl1.1.1
3. wget [http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.20_amd64.deb](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1%7E18.04.20_amd64.deb)
4. Then install
5. sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.20_amd64.deb

Hope this helps others who are trying to do the same.

The issue is referenced in https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/24759.

All credit goes to @feisalramar.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the command **sudo apt install mongodb** it will install the mongodb, because mongodb is now part of ubuntu repository. After installation run command **sudo service mongodb start** to start the mongodb server. Then if you run command  **mongo** it will give you shell helper. To see the existing database use command  **show dbs**. After successfull installation you will find there pre existing database names are **admin, config, local**. Use command **db** to see  which database is currently running on server, there will a database named **test or somthing**. To add a collection (tables on SQL DB) just use the insert command with an initial document (row in SQL DB) information **db.data.insert({"username":"Brad Pitt"})**

In previous command **data** is my collection name.
Now to see all documents in data collection just use command **db.data.find()**;
Other commands:
 **sudo service mongod status, sudo service mongodb stop, sudo service mongod restart ,sudo service mongod stop.**

For more information, you can visit https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

;
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me on Pop_OS Linux 20.04 LTS helped:

1. `$ sudo apt-get purge mongodb*`

Then creating `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list` file for Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) via this command:

2. `$ echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list`

instead of Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal)

After that install mongodb-org:

3. `$ sudo apt-get update` 
   `$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`

And start mongodb service:

4. `$ sudo systemctl start mongod`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is only on **Ubuntu 22.04**,

Try this out:

```sh
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libssl1.1
```

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 is Jammy - why do want to install packages from Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish) to it?

Answer (score -1):

Try this, I successfully find this out

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message you're seeing indicates that there are unmet dependencies when trying to install MongoDB-related packages. To resolve this issue, you can follow these steps:

1. Remove Conflicting Packages:

> sudo apt purge mongodb-org*
>
> sudo apt autoremove

2. Update Your Package List:

> sudo apt update

Install Dependencies Manually:
You may need to install the dependencies manually. In this case, it seems like the required packages are mongodb-org-server, mongodb-org-mongos, and mongodb-database-tools. Try installing them individually:bash

> sudo apt install mongodb-org-server

> mongodb-org-mongos sudo apt install

> mongodb-database-toolssudo apt install