# unmet-dependencies-when-trying-to-install

Tags: linux, dependencies, apt

```
abhijith@abhijith-Lenovo-G580:`~$ sudo apt install john`:

Reading package lists... Done. 
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done   
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.  
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
john : Depends: john-data (= 1.8.0-2build1) but it is not going to be 
installed    
mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed  
Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed  
 E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: problem solved  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51418044/13298558

Answer (score 3):

Try executing the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
sudo apt update
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Hope this may help.