# I screwed up my installation of MongoDB and I need help removing it to reinstall it

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Just to be transparent, ***I don't know how*** but I'm sure I dug myself into a hole. Assume I'm donkey-brain. This is a brand new install of Ubuntu - I have zero precious data on this so there will be nothing lost I care about if I need to remove literally anything.

I tried to install MongoDB on Ubuntu 20.04. I realized there was a different way to do it later, but I followed my schools instructions to install it using homebrew. That didn't really work out too well for me so I found a different guide from the school that covered the Ubuntu installation. I followed that by doing the following

```
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt-get install mongodb
    mongod --version \\which works still, returns im on version 3.6.8
```

Then the guide goes over starting and stopping the service with and checking it
`sudo service mongodb status` but that returns `Unit mongodb.service could not be found`

I figured my installation is screwed, I messed it up somewhere or something so I'll just find a guide to uninstall and re-install. So I started looking for a guide to uninstall and I found this [Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092353/failed-to-start-mongod-service-unit-mongod-service-not-found) so I tried that uninstall guide with 58 votes.

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

Which basically tells me those things aren't there. So I thought I would be good to continue with the install since I couldn't even find the things I wanted to remove. So I proceeded with the install side which went fine for the first few steps but I got stuck here -

```
➜  lib sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mongodb-org is already the newest version (5.0.3).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-database : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
➜  lib sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-program-options1.71.0 libgoogle-perftools4 libpcrecpp0v5
  libsnappy1v5 libtcmalloc-minimal4 libyaml-cpp0.6 mongodb-server-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/44.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 183 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 224051 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_5.0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (5.0.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_5.0.3_
amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-
core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_5.0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (5.0.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_5.0.3_
amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-
core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_5.0.3_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_5.0.3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
➜  lib sudo service mongodb status
[sudo] password for brainzilla: 
Unit mongodb.service could not be found.
```

So I'm kind of stuck, I don't really know where to look at this point tbh. I had it working at one point the other night, but I believe it came down to some ownership issue of the config file?? And I can't remember where that guide went on my rampage went. But I was able get my project from school, run `nodemon start` and it showed I was connected to localhost:27017 and everything. I rebooted my PC just to see if I would run into anything weird the next day and sure enough it wouldn't work again. *I tried to find the guide I had referenced before but I lost it...*

Comment: Did you check [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)? Follow this guideline carefully. Note statement *The mongodb package provided by Ubuntu is not maintained by MongoDB Inc. and conflicts with the official mongodb-org package. If you have already installed the mongodb package on your Ubuntu system, you must first uninstall the mongodb package before proceeding with these instructions.*

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, the uninstall commands I tried were directly from that guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that my problem was that I was running commands in zsh and not in Bash. So I did `exec bash` and then the following from this stack overflow [Unable to install mongodb properly on ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417708/unable-to-install-mongodb-properly-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

You need to first uninstall the mongodb, you can use:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

After this, install mongodb through the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

And then update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You are done with the installation of mongodb. You can check it by using the below command:

```
mongo --version
```

Once I was done and everything looked good. Ran `exec zsh` to get back to zsh, then tested my app again by running nodemon and everything is good.