# downloading mongoDB with error "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-20.04

I'm downloading mongoDB on **Linux Ubuntu Version 22.04.1 LTS**, facing download error

I tried 3 solution from stack overflow discussion

> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

```
(base) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm not sure what solution can perfectly solve my problem, that I need a hand here

I post on ask Ubuntu too the sister site, there I post more details as possible cause when I update here,system keep knowledge me posting format incorrect.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434992/downloading-mongodb-with-error-e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-bro

Comment: Please do not post such questions on multiple sites. Choose one where this is a on-topic question

Comment: previous was 2 site, now I changed into one site now, thanks

Comment: Your problem is still posted on askubuntu.com (where this is on-topic) and StackOverflow (where it is off-topic)

Comment: hi@Nico Haase , I just ask the same way like this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417708/unable-to-install-mongodb-properly-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts), cause that discussion could't solve my problem so that I want more possibility to solve this issue. But if you wish, I can delete this question for you, if you still consider asking here is off-topic.

Comment: You can install using .tar.gz option, and not via apt-get since it's LTS support is up to 20.* at this moment.

Answer (score -1):

**Stennie from MongoDB Community Team said that**:

> MongoDB build team is aware and will set up appropriate packaging & testing infrastructure to validate new packages.
>
> > 1. Run your MongoDB deployment on separate hosts with supported O/S versions (eg 20.04 LTS)
> > 2. Run MongoDB in a container/VM with a supported O/S version
> > 3. Use a hosted version of MongoDB (eg MongoDB Atlas) so you have fewer direct dependencies on O/S updates

In my opinion MongoDB may not be in Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy) yet because they didn't explain the installation process on the official web site.